# How to set geofencing region and send notification to user when he is in the Geofencing region

Tags: android, google-maps, android-notifications, geofencing

i want to make geolocation aware application by using geofencing.

i want to set notification alarm or user when he is in geofencing location, he can set geofencing location by long pressing on google map.

how to make this project ?

Answer (score 0):

The [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/location/geofencing.html) discusses building geofencing, you can read more about it there.